No guarda fecha y hora en campo date de bd oracle
Tengo un problema con un campo de tipo date en Oracle ya que no guarda la fecha y hora actual; solo guarda la fecha.  Hago un insert desde una app java y coloco, donde va el campo fecha, SYSDATE para que me inserte fecha y hora y solo inserta fecha. Ya intenté colocar CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, TO_CHAR(sysdate,'dd/mm/yy hh;mm:ss'), SYSDATE  y no ha funcionado. ¿Será que el tipo de dato debe ser timespan en lugar de date?
"Insert into act (id,folio,claveservicio,idcontri,clvusuario,fecha,fecharegistro,fechaact,clvusuaruiact,concluye,observaciones,clvstatus) values(?, select nvl(max(folio)+1) from act),?,?,?, to_date('"+sdf.format(obj.consulta.getFecha())+"','dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'),sysdate,sysdate,?,?,?,?)";

Este es el resultado al consultar mi tabla desde Orcale SQL Developer v. 22.2.1.234 y donde solo se muestra la fecha sin la hora


¿ TIMESPAN o TIMESTAMP?

¿Cómo estás haciendo la inserción desde la app hecha en java?

Existe una remota chance de que si te este guardando la hora, pero que la hacer el select, solo estes viendo la fecha por culpa de tu ide ;)

Ojo: ¿cómo tenés la certeza de que se está guardando solo la fecha? ¿Desde dónde estás viendo los datos? Lo que te mencionó gbianchi es fundamental.

tu insert demuestra efectivamente que lo estas ingresando.. volve a mi comentario original.. como lo estas intentando mostrar?? donde?? con que query???

@gbianchi donde veo mis resultados es atraves de Oracle SQL Developer y es donde veo que solo se inserto la fecha, realmente  no se si ese ide es el que me esta causando ese problema

@gbianchi ya revise y efectivamente como lo has comentado es el IDE que estoy usando el que no me permite ver la hora, si esto esta ocurriendo hay forma de que se visualice la hora o tendria que cambiar de. IDE?..  Gracias!

Dale el formato de fecha y hora en el select :)

sql developer no muestra las horsa por defecto...tenes que tocar tu select para que las muestre..
